# Angular 7 animation trigger causes console error

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, angular-animations

I am trying to set up a fadeInOut animation on a component. 
**My app module imports BrowserAnimationsModule.**

I created an animation and a trigger in a separate file:

```
import { animate, style, animation, trigger, useAnimation, transition } from '@angular/animations';

export const fadeIn = animation([style({ opacity: 0 }), animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))]);
export const fadeOut = animation(animate('500ms', style({ opacity: 0 })));

export const fadeInOut = trigger('fadeInOut', [
  transition('void => *', useAnimation(fadeIn)),
  transition('* => void', useAnimation(fadeOut))
]);
```

Then, I created a component and verified that the component itself works:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Globals } from '@app/globals';
import { fadeInOut } from '@app/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-global-alert',
  template: `
    <div class="global-alert" *ngIf="globalAlert">
      <div class="global-alert-message"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
      <div class="close" (click)="closeGlobalAlert()"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [],
  animations: [fadeInOut]
})
export class GlobalAlertComponent implements OnInit {
  private globalAlert: boolean;

  constructor(private globals: Globals) {
    this.globalAlert = globals.hasGlobalAlert;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  closeGlobalAlert() {
    this.globals.hasGlobalAlert = false;
    this.globalAlert = false;
  }
}
```

Note that I am storing the state of whether this alert should appear in a globals.ts file, although that's unrelated:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  hasGlobalAlert = true;
}
```

So I use the component inside another component's html like so:

```
<div>
lots of html
</div>
   <app-global-alert>Hello world</app-global-alert>
```

This works, the alert is dismissed when you click the close button, everything works as expected.  However, when I try to add my trigger to it

```
   <app-global-alert [@fadeInOut]>Hello world</app-global-alert>
```

I get a console error
`Error: Found the synthetic property @fadeInOut. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.`

I've Googled this, but AFAICT I've covered all the gotchas in most of the replies:  I've included the `animations` declaration in the component, etc.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in official  [docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations#step-3-adding-the-animation-metadata-property), animation should be added to component's metadata property. There's such property in `GlobalAlertComponent` here:

```
@Component({
  animations: [fadeInOut],
  ...
})
export class GlobalAlertComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

This allows to use animation on any element inside of `html` part of this component. But `@fadeInOut` animation has been used in another component's `html` here:

```
<div>
  lots of html
</div>
  <app-global-alert [@fadeInOut]>Hello world</app-global-alert>
```

Make sure this component has import and animation property in its metadata.

Comment: This fixed the error, although the actual animation is not working yet.  I think it's because my ngIf is inside the component's template and not on the component itself.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  I moved everything into the global alert component, including the trigger.  Works now.  Thanks @vadi

Answer (score -1):

I get a console error Error: `Found the synthetic property @fadeInOut. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.`

This error occurs when you have not imported `"BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule"` module in your component containing Module. If your animation component is in App module then check if app.module is having the following in the @NgModule -

```
@NgModule({  
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule //or NoopAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Just want to confirm if your GlobalAlertComponent is part of AppModule, not another feature module? If it is part of the feature module then respective feature module must have BrowserAnimationsModule imported.

Comment: `GlobalAlertComponent` is part of `SharedModule`. If I try to import `BrowserAnimationsModule` into `SharedModule` I get a different error `Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded.`.  If I try **removing** it from AppModule, I still get the error.

Comment: Please try reexport BroswerAnimationModule in shared module i.e. exports: BrowserAnimationModule and remove reference from App module.

Comment: See accepted answer:  it turns out had nothing to do with the module.  I think angular should throw a more helpful error here.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add `BrowserAnimationsModule`
In app-module.ts file in import section.

```
import: [
BrowserAnimationsModule
]
```

Hope it will help.
Happy coding :)